# Wordpress Custom Css not updating when accessing website from mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, styles, genesis

I am using Aspire Pro WordPress Theme.
I have added some custom css from customizer, css is updating when access the website from desktop or laptop. I have checked styling for mobile using chrome tools. It is working fine.

But when i access website from mobile custom styles not showing.
Website Link: https://williamlsnowden.com

Comment: Try clearing the cache on your phone.

Comment: I have tried clearing cache. Can you check on your mobile?

Comment: I am not allowed to click unknown websites from my mom

Comment: williamlsnowden 
Just google it and open the website from there.

Comment: What was the css code that you add from customizer ?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually your code.... The custom code you need in not here....
I added into the **** lines.....
Try it and clean cache

```
<style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css">

.site-header{
    background-color: #247f34;
}

.site-header.light{
    display: none;
    background-color: #f16334;
}

.footer-widgets, .site-footer {
    background-color: #000;
}

.front-page-1 {
    height: 80vh;
}

.site-footer a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}
.after-entry {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.front-page-2 {
    height: 80%;
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

.flexible-widgets .widget {
    margin: 0;
}

.image-section {
    padding: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px){

         *****************************************************************
         ***************************************************************
          .front-page-1 { 
                 background-repeat: no-repeat !important; 
                 background-size: contain !important; 
                 background-position:center !important;
           } 
          ***************************************************************
         *****************************************************************

    .front-page-2 .enews-widget     input {
            width: 100%;
    }

    /*.front-page-1 {
            background-image: url(//williamlsnowden.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/cover2-mobile.png);
    }*/

}
</style>
```

Comment: I just come to know that my custom css only updating when i logged into website. Not when i logout o.O Strange 
 Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: Maybe it is because you are put the code in a php page or html page. It is better if you put your css code into only one css page , then link it to all the application